# Scene graph in Unity3D

Tags: unity, rotation, scene-graph

I was wondering if any scene graph-like mechanism is implemented into Unity3D? For example if I have a GameObject, can I add child cubes to it so when I rotate the parent GameObject, the siblings will rotate too?

Comment: Note only does it exist, it is fundamental to the way Unity works.  You'll be hard pressed to build anyrhing usable that doesn't have a fairly intricate scene graph in Unity.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Transform component has Parent Transform. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html